# How to reduce the size of React Native Expo app

Tags: react-native

When I build and obtain the APK of my React Native app, the size is always a bit high compared to the app. I code simple app its increase and decreasing when touch buttons. How can I reduce the size of the app?

I haven't found a solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

if u are using `eas` u can try this one below

```js
{
  "expo": {
    "plugins": [
      [
        "expo-build-properties",
        {
          "android": {
            "enableProguardInReleaseBuilds": true,
          }
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

[Expo-Documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/build-properties/#pluginconfigtypeandroid)

- removing un wanted or un used library
- un used codes, images etc..
- optimising images fonts etc...
- code splitting

these will help to reduce the app size